# Python generator - yield nothing or jump to next?

Tags: python, list, generator

I wrote a Python code snippet.

```
def all_but(n):
    for i in range(10):
        if i != n:
            yield i

>>> list(all_but(5))
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Well, the output is what I expected. But I don't fully understand what happens when i == 5. Does the generator yield nothing, or it jumps to next to yield 6?

Comment: It jumps to the next iteration of the loop. WIthout even hitting `yield` on this iteration, because `if` condition results in false.

Comment: @YaroslavAdmin Ah. So the generator will yield until it hits yield. Well, I feel like I am talking an obvious fact.

Comment: It's the `if` condition which is skipping when `n=5`, so when that happens, it just goes to the next iteration without executing `yield i`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summarized from comments, **the generator output whenever it hits the 'yield' keyword**.